# Cointegration coefficients with R (ca.jo function)

Tags: r, cointegration

I am trying to study the relation between some macroeconomic variables of a country.
I ran a cointegration test with the ca.jo function in R, which shows a rank 2 cointegration. I have troubles to interpret the coefficients matrix I obtained, that's why I am asking for your help...

```
Test type: trace statistic , with linear trend

Eigenvalues (lambda):
[1] 0.599037 0.360113 0.236137
Values of teststatistic and critical values of test:

           test  10pct   5pct   1pct
r <= 2 |  68.66  66.49  70.60  78.87
r <= 1 | 107.05  85.18  90.39 104.20
r = 0  | 185.65 118.99 124.25 136.06

Eigenvectors, normalised to first column:
(These are the cointegration relations)

            IPFRA.l2  BSMFRA.l2  CPIFRA.l2    
IPFRA.l2    1.000000   1.000000  1.0000000     
BSMFRA.l2   3.333591  -0.043656 -0.3723095  
CPIFRA.l2   7.484742   0.054972  3.0748536   


Weights W:
(This is the loading matrix)

           IPFRA.l2 BSMFRA.l2 CPIFRA.l2      
IPFRA.d  -0.0025670 -0.045954 -0.034443   
BSMFRA.d -0.0442384 -0.670880  0.018791    
CPIFRA.d -0.0001183  0.022792  0.008217
```

My ultimate goal is to be able to write an equation like:
cpifra=beta1*ipfra + beta2*bsmfra

I guess I should take my betas into the eigenvectors table, but I don't know how to pick and process them.

Comment: Don't worry about "hello" and "thank you". Here at Cross Validated these are perceived as nuisance that clutter the post. As long as your tone is not offensive, everyone will be alright :)

Comment: First, save your result as an object, and use @ to pick the matrix as you want.

Comment: As I understand it the original question is not how to extract the numbers from the model in R, but a problem of interpretation on how to decide which numbers to use

Answer (score 0):

I try to answer your question. From what you done, it is called Johansen procedure to check cointegration of multiple time series and is useful for testing more than 2 time series (i.e. 3, 4, 5 etc). I see that you are using 3 time series since there are three list of rank (r) in the result.

The null hypothesis (H0) is r=0 indicate **no cointegration** exists for all combination of your time series. From your result, it shows that the test statistic for r=0 is more than all critical values (1%, 5% and 10%), hence we can reject H0 meaning your combination of 3 time series is cointegrated.

The test result of the highest rank (r <= 2) indicate that you may reject H0 but in more relaxed critical value (10%), meaning that even if you use only 1 time series it is already stationer (you don't need to combine with other time series), but, it is on more relaxed critical value so maybe this inference is quite weak.

The matrix below rank is showing eigenvector component for each time series (variable). For example, for IPFRA.l2, the components are 1.000000, 3.333591, 7.484742. If you multiply the component with its corresponding variable dataset, you can get cointegration value.
Visualizing the value you can observe that combination between all your time series is actually resembling a white noise (not significantly different from zero).
[image: source: https://www.quantstart.com]

> example image of cointegration value sourced from https://www.quantstart.com

I don't see if you can write down model equation from the Johansen procedure result since it is a testing for cointegration not for building a model.

If you want to make a model from the result, you need to proceed to modelling process i.e. VECM or dynamic regression model (linear regression model with ARIMA to handle non-stationer).
For how to build a dynamic model you can read here [dynamic model with R](https://otexts.com/fpp3/dynamic.html)

You can read more detail explanation about Johansen procedure here [quantstart.com](https://www.quantstart.com/articles/Johansen-Test-for-Cointegrating-Time-Series-Analysis-in-R/)

Hope this help you and future reader.